# Different among __weak, __block and __assign?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, block, null, weak-references

1) Wikipedia said: "The difference between weak (_*weak) and assign (*_assign) is that when the object the variable pointed to is being deallocated, whether the value of the variable is going to be changed or not. weak ones will be updated to nil and the assign one will be left unchanged, as a dangling pointer."

But after I tried a sample in Xcode like this

```
__weak NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[obj1 release];
```

If Wiki's right, the address obj1 pointed to must be `nill`  after release. But the address obj1 pointed to is still `0xabcdef...`
Wiki's wrong ?

2) Help me distinguish `__weak, __block, __assign` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as `__assign`. You can define properties with the `assign` attribute but there is no `__assign` keyword like there is with `__weak`. And `__block` has nothing at all to do with the main part of your question.

Comment: So Wiki's right or wrong ???

Comment: I read that topic but I still don't understand about __weak, __block

Comment: The Wikipedia article is correct. But understand that the variable may not be set to `nil` instantly. There are cases where it isn't set to `nil` until a little later. Some of this may depend on optimization levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__weak` attribute for "Zeroing weak references" is ***only available*** with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).

Your code is obviously compiled with MRC (Manual Reference Counting). In that case,
the `__weak attribute` is just ***ignored*** and you should get a compiler warning

```
__weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable when ARC is not enabled [-Wignored-attributes]
```

Therefore, releasing the object has ***no effect*** on the `obj1` variable itself. It is a
*dangling pointer*, pointing to a deallocated instance.

---

If you convert your code to ARC then you have to remove the `release` statement. 
Now you will get a different warning

```
assigning retained object to weak variable; object will be released after assignment [-Warc-unsafe-retained-assign]
```

The object will be deallocated and `obj1` set to `nil` immediately, because there are no strong references to the object after the assignment.